# Compare lists and give me what isn't in list a that is in list b

Tags: c++

I have 2 lists. Let's call them A and B. Is there a neat stl trick to see what list B has that list A doesn't without myself manually looping over them with an iterator comparing the elements myself?

Comment: yes.  there is a neat stl trick to see what list B has that list A doesn't

Comment: [set_difference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/) maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::set_difference`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/)

> The difference of two sets is formed by the elements that are present in the first set, but not in the second one. The elements copied by the function come always from the first range, in the same order.

Note that the two lists have to be sorted.

Here is a sample that shows example of usage:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   list<int> a {1,2,3,4,5,10};
   list<int> b {4,5,6,7,11};
   list<int> out;
   set_difference(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end(), back_inserter(out));
   cout << "out size is " << out.size() << endl;
   for(auto i: out)
   {
      cout << i << endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you might be able to use the set_difference algorithm  [set-difference discription](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_difference/)

and here is a c++ example [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)